# Blender not show texture of brush

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I started study  blender and got a bit problem. When i apply a texture in Texture Paint showed a texture preview, but after some exercicies, this options not show. I maked a ss to show my problem.

[image]

I use blender 3.6.5

Comment: Hello, if you plan to paint with the Stencil option in the Image Editor, make sure that you've selected the image on which you want to paint, is it the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I changed to 0% in Texture Opacity Cursor. link to refer: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/cursor.html